# testrpc throws when I set a state variable to 0

Tags: solidity, contract-development, testrpc

Any idea why calling set() on this contract throws `base fee exceeds gas limit` when executed on testrpc 6.0.3 via Remix IDE?

```
/* Calling set() works fine on javascriptVM, fails on testrpc/ganache-cli 6.0.3 */
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Test {

  uint public counter = 1;

  function set() public  {
      counter = 0;
  }

}
```

See [this bug report](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/issues/458) as well.